# print mysql date using smarty

Tags: php, mysql, date, smarty

i put date in mysql database with this method `2012-08-02 02:20:05`. now, how to print in my page using smarty.

mycode : ( NOTE: send_date is name of row )

```
$sql = "SELECT m.*, s.photo, s.gender
       FROM mail AS m, signup AS s
       WHERE m.receiver = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($username). "'
       AND m.sender = s.username AND inbox = '1' AND status = '1'
       ORDER BY send_date DESC LIMIT " .$limit;
$rs  = $conn->execute($sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a date from `2012-08-02 02:20:05` to unix epoch (seconds since 1970), you want to use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime). To format an epoch to any human readable date you want to use [date()](http://php.net/date) or [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime).

Smarty knows the [date_format modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl). Since Smarty3 this puppy accepts pretty much anything that represents a date (including `2012-08-02 02:20:05`). In Smarty2 you might need to convert the string to epoch yourself, something like {$date|strtotime|date_forma:"%d.$m.%Y"}. Note that since Smarty3 date_format accepts format notations from strtotime and date, while Smarty2 only supported the strtotime notation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to output any variable in smarty do the following (assuming your smarty is set up correctly):

In PHP:

```
/*
assign method: assigns variables to the template
first parameter: The variable name you want to use in your template file
second parameter: the parameter you want to pass to your template file
*/
$smarty->assign('variable', $variable);
```

In smarty:

```
/*
brackets {} indicate that smarty is in play
$variable is the variable you passed to smarty
*/

{$variable}
```

If this is not what you're after please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: I know! how to create $variable ?

Comment: The $variable is the value you retrieve from your database I assume.